# Cython: Two prange inside a "with nogil, parallel()" possible?

Tags: parallel-processing, cython

I have here using cython's parallel loop. This example is almost like the example in the documentation. The difference is that when I populate the local buffer, I also use prange. 
The real case would involve the func having loops of its own that uses local_buf in the innermost loop.

What I don't understand is, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't + IDE frozen. If I switch the first loop to using range, then there is no problem, IDE doesn't hang and result obtained is correct.

I was under the impression it would parallel the first loop, finished, then move on to second loop and run parallelize. So there would be no overlap between first or second loop. Is this assumption wrong ?

Is this not possible to do ?

```
with nogil, parallel():
    local_buf = <int *> malloc(sizeof(int) * size)
    if local_buf == NULL:
        abort()

    # populate our local buffer in a sequential loop
    for i in prange(size):  ## using prange to populate for speed
        local_buf[i] = i * 2

    # share the work using the thread-local buffer(s)
    for j in prange(n):
        func(local_buf)
```

Comment: I don't think the first loop as `prange` makes any sense. Each local buffer needs to be initialized fully in every thread. The first loop being `prange` means that only a little bit of the local buffer is initialized. I also don't think this very basic initialization would benefit from being parallelized anyway, but that's slightly tangential to the question. It isn't clear why it should freeze the IDE, but that could be from any of the things you don't show here

Comment: @DavidW, Thank you ! Makes sense to me now.